# i have a problem with requests post in python

Tags: python, python-requests

```
url = "http://www.yyy.com/y.php"
c = requests.Session()
uid = 180
r = c.post(url, data={"z&id": uid})
```

"post method"
script is error, cannot sent the value. I want the result to be like this:
http://www.yyy.com/y.php?z&id=180

HOW?

Comment: change `post` to get.

Comment: sorry the url is url = "http://www.yyy.com/y.php" and method is post data={"z&id": uid}  . and result error

Comment: use `params` argument, not `data` to append query string to a url

Answer (score 1):

Change your post request to get and send z and id as two parameters instead of one.